# How is fma() implemented

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754, instruction-set, fma

According to the [documentation](http://sourceware.org/newlib/libm.html#fma), there is a `fma()` function in `math.h`. That is very nice, and I know how FMA works and what to use it for. However, I am not so certain how this is implemented in practice? I'm mostly interested in the `x86` and `x86_64` architectures.

Is there a floating-point (non-vector) instruction for FMA, perhaps as defined by IEEE-754 2008?

Is FMA3 or FMA4 instruction used?

Is there an intrinsic to make sure that a real FMA is used, when the precision is relied upon?

Comment: On x86 and x86_64, gcc emits fma instructions if it's told it's allowed to (`-mfma` or `-mfma4` or `-march=something` where `something` is a fma-supporting processor).  On Linux, you might look at `sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_fma.c` in glibc to get an idea of what the library function fallback looks like.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The actual implementation varies from platform to platform, but speaking very broadly:

- If you tell your compiler to target a machine with hardware FMA instructions (PowerPC, ARM with VFPv4 or AArch64, Intel Haswell or AMD Bulldozer and onwards), the compiler *may* replace calls to `fma( )` by just dropping the appropriate instruction into your code.  This is not guaranteed, but is generally good practice.  Otherwise you will get a call to the math library, and:
- When running on a processor that has hardware FMA, those instructions should be used to implement the function.  However, if you have an older version of your operating system, or an older version of the math library, it may not take advantage of those instructions.
- If you are running on a processor that does not have hardware FMA, or you are using an older (or just not very good) math library, then a software implementation of FMA will be used instead.  This might be implemented using clever extended-precision floating-point tricks, or with integer arithmetic.
- The result of the `fma( )` function should always be correctly rounded (i.e. a "real fma").  If it is not, that's a bug in your system's math library.  Unfortunately, `fma( )` is one of the more difficult math library functions to implement correctly, so many implementations have bugs.  Please report them to your library vendor so they get fixed!

> Is there an intrinsic to make sure that a real FMA is used, when the precision is relied upon?

Given a good compiler, this shouldn't be necessary; it should suffice to use the `fma( )` function and tell the compiler what architecture you are targeting.  However, compilers are not perfect, so you may need to use the `_mm_fmadd_sd( )` and related intrinsics on x86 (but report the bug to your compiler vendor!)

Comment: “An opportunity to explain round-to-odd is like the tour de France: one waits for it for a long time and it passes quickly.”

Comment: @PascalCuoq IEEE-754 uses round to even by default, if I'm not mistaken. Why is round to odd relevant in this context? I'm currently implementing a multiple-precision library so I'm little bit familiar with the inner workings, but I've not heard of round to odd being particularly important. Very poetic btw, well done!

Comment: @theswine If you have a format with twice the width of the FMA you aim for, you can do the multiplication without error. Say that you are implementing `fmaf` with a double-precision `double`. You are left with the problem of adding a `double` value of `(double)a*(double)b` and a `float c` and round this addition to the nearest `float`. This operation is not generally available but can be implemented as a `double` addition in round-to-odd followed by rounding from `double` to `float` in round-to-nearest. Not using round-to-odd for the intermediate result causes double-rounding issues.

Comment: @theswine See it in code: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.glibc.alpha/15546

Comment: @PascalCuoq Oh, I see. That is rather elegant. If I was implementing fma in software, I would go in the way of calculating the approximate result and the correction, as an expansion. This can then be rounded to the nearest representable number. It has the advantage that it can be done with double as well (without the need for long double support), but for floats it would be likely slower in terms of operation count. However, changing the x86 rounding mode is quite slow, so in the end it might be comparable to double and round to odd

Comment: @PascalCuoq did you write that patch by any chance?

Comment: I didn't write the patch I linked to, but I did write a correct (AFAICT) `fmaf` using the naïve approach: (assuming a, b, c ≥ 0) http://ideone.com/kx7MXE . And you should also look at this implementation if you are interested in the subject: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libm/Libm-315/Source/Intel/xmm_fma.c

Comment: @PascalCuoq are you sure your `fmaf` is correct? If I understand it correctly, you are multiplying / adding exactly representable integers, yielding an exactly representable result. While that tests that it indeed calculates `a + b * c`, I believe it does not test the rounding, not to mention overflow handling. I could be wrong, though, and I'm certainly not claiming the routine as flawed - just the unit test.

Comment: @theswine I think both the implementation and the test are pretty good for a comment in reply to a tangential remark on a blog post (the context in which this function was written). I do not understand what you are saying about rounding. Are you saying that there is no rounding in `float truefma = (long long) a * b + c;`?

Comment: @theswine I admit that the test is unnecessarily limited: all these masks with `0xfffff` should be masks with `0xffffff`. I will see if ideone lets me change it.

Comment: @PascalCuoq sorry, I did not mean to criticize and I think your code is great, but you wrote it for some purpose, not because of me. And I'm grateful for a bunch of interesting papers about round-to-odd. I was just wondering if the test could be improved somehow. I think if you multiply slightly longer numbers as int64, and then shift to 23 fraction bits (since it is float), you will be able to simulate and check the rounding.

Comment: @theswine rounding in the conversion of `a`, `b` or `c` to `float` is unnecessary and indeed a nuisance that would have to be controlled if it happened. As long as there is rounding in the conversion of the `long long` value `(long long) a * b + c` to `float` (and such a conversion happens implicitly in the assignment `float truefma = …`), the test is testing the `myfma`'s behavior with respect to rounding. Rounding happens during this assignment because of the values of the various masks applied to the results of `rand()`. Therefore, the test is testing `myfma`'s behavior with rounding.

Comment: @theswine You understand what `(rand() & 0xFFFFFF) << (rand() & 7)` and `(long long)(rand() & 0xFFFFFF) << (rand() & 31)` do, right?

Comment: @PascalCuoq It generates two (up to) 24-bit numbers, which are both exactly representable as float (one implicit bit + 23 fraction ones). Their product is going to be twice the width so it would round off and the sum likewise. I see, I thought you would need to explicitly round the integer to nearest even, I did not realize it happens automatically in the conversion to float - I expected to see some bit operations there. It will not check if FPU mode is e.g. round towards zero (but then again, your routine would likely not work anyway in such case, you just never know if it happens).

Comment: @PascalCuoq However, you may want to make sure that RAND_MAX is a power of two greater than `0xffffff`, on some platforms it is not. Apologies for lengthy comments. If you just hate the discussion at this point, we don't have to continue. I'm just trying to contribute.

Answer (score 6):

One way to implement FMA in software is by splitting the significant into high and low bits. I use [Dekker's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285492/efficient-way-to-round-double-precision-numbers-to-a-lower-precision-given-in-nu/14285800#14285800)

```
typedef struct { float hi; float lo; } doublefloat;  
doublefloat split(float a) {
    float t = ((1<<12)+1)*a;
    float hi = t - (t - a);
    float lo = a - hi;
    return (doublefloat){hi, lo};
}
```

Once you split the the float you can calculate `a*b-c` with a single rounding like this

```
float fmsub(float a, float b, float c) {
    doublefloat as = split(a), bs = split(b);
    return ((as.hi*bs.hi - c) + as.hi*bs.lo + as.lo*bs.hi) + as.lo*bs.lo;
}
```

This basically subtracts `c` from `(ahi,alo)*(bhi,blo) = (ahi*bhi + ahi*blo + alo*bhi + alo*blo)`.

I got this idea from the `twoProd` function in the paper [Extended-Precision Floating-Point Numbers for GPU Computation](http://andrewthall.org/papers/df64_qf128.pdf) and from the `mul_sub_x` function in [Agner Fog's vector class library](http://agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass). He uses a different function for splitting vectors of floats which splits differently. I tried to reproduce a scalar version here

```
typedef union {float f; int i;} u;
doublefloat split2(float a) {
    u lo, hi = {a};
    hi.i &= -(1<<12);
    lo.f = a - hi.f;
    return (doublefloat){hi.f,lo.f};
}
```

In any case using `split` or `split2` in `fmsub` agrees well with `fma(a,b,-c)` from the math library in glibc. For whatever reason my version is significantly faster than `fma` except on a machine that has hardware fma (in which case I use `_mm_fmsub_ss` anyway).

Comment: Nice references. I'm aware of Schewchuk's and Priest's work. In this question I was more interested about what instructions there are in the current instructions sets. I guess `_mm_fmadd_ss` pretty much sums it up.

Comment: Your version might be faster since it does not handle special numbers (especially infinities). I might be wrong but it seems that multiply / add with infinity will cause Dekker's algorithm to generate NaNs. I'd expect the runtime to behave correctly there, hence the speed penalty.

Comment: There is far more than `_mm_fmadd_ss` for the x86 set (and `_mm_fmadd_ps` is more interesting to me anyway) if you want to see all of them go to [IntrinsicsGuide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) and under Technologies select FMA.

Comment: @theswine, good point about the special numbers. That may explain the speed penalty with `fma` for glibc.

Comment: What about computing `a*b+c`?

Comment: @plasmacel, I think you change `(as.hi*bs.hi - c)` to `(as.hi*bs.hi + c)`.

Answer (score 6):

Z boson's FMA suggestion based on Dekker's algorithm is unfortunately incorrect. Unlike in Dekker's twoProduct, in the more general FMA case the magnitude of c is not known relative to the product terms, and hence wrong cancellations can occur.

So, while Dekker's twoProduct can be greatly accelerated with a hardware FMA, the error term computation of Dekker's twoProduct is *not* a robust FMA implementation.

A correct implementation would need to either use a summation algorithm with higher than double precision, or add the terms in decreasing order of magnitude.

Comment: Note that he is doing `fmsub`. Assuming that the quantities are positive, I'd say his implementation works. Anyway, a bright comment from someone with 11 xp, good work.

Comment: Yeah, no, you're right. If `c` is very small then it is swamped by roundoff when subtracted from `ahi*bhi` and it does not help at all. He'd need to form a longer expansion and start adding from the smallest element using essentially what is known as Kahan's summation. Even though the result is rounded to float, this ordering still matters as it can affect the roundoff direction.

Comment: I wrote a quick remark about the Kahan summation not quite being sufficient here, and then realized you really meant doing _both_, sorting the input by magnitude and then adding with Kahan summation.I completely agree that the combination will produce a correctly rounded FMA result.