# Intel FMA Instructions Offer Zero Performance Advantage

Tags: c, assembly, avx2, fma

Consider the following instruction sequence using Haswell's FMA instructions:

```
  __m256 r1 = _mm256_xor_ps (r1, r1);
  r1 = _mm256_fmadd_ps (rp1, m6, r1);
  r1 = _mm256_fmadd_ps (rp2, m7, r1);
  r1 = _mm256_fmadd_ps (rp3, m8, r1);

  __m256 r2 = _mm256_xor_ps (r2, r2);
  r2 = _mm256_fmadd_ps (rp1, m3, r2);
  r2 = _mm256_fmadd_ps (rp2, m4, r2);
  r2 = _mm256_fmadd_ps (rp3, m5, r2);

  __m256 r3 = _mm256_xor_ps (r3, r3);
  r3 = _mm256_fmadd_ps (rp1, m0, r3);
  r3 = _mm256_fmadd_ps (rp2, m1, r3);
  r3 = _mm256_fmadd_ps (rp3, m2, r3);
```

The same computation can be expressed using non-FMA instructions as follows:

```
  __m256 i1 = _mm256_mul_ps (rp1, m6);
  __m256 i2 = _mm256_mul_ps (rp2, m7);
  __m256 i3 = _mm256_mul_ps (rp3, m8);
  __m256 r1 = _mm256_xor_ps (r1, r1);
  r1 = _mm256_add_ps (i1, i2);
  r1 = _mm256_add_ps (r1, i3);

  i1 = _mm256_mul_ps (rp1, m3);
  i2 = _mm256_mul_ps (rp2, m4);
  i3 = _mm256_mul_ps (rp3, m5);
  __m256 r2 = _mm256_xor_ps (r2, r2);
  r2 = _mm256_add_ps (i1, i2);
  r2 = _mm256_add_ps (r2, i3);

  i1 = _mm256_mul_ps (rp1, m0);
  i2 = _mm256_mul_ps (rp2, m1);
  i3 = _mm256_mul_ps (rp3, m2);
  __m256 r3 = _mm256_xor_ps (r3, r3);
  r3 = _mm256_add_ps (i1, i2);
  r3 = _mm256_add_ps (r3, i3);
```

One would expect the FMA version to provide some performance advantage over the non-FMA version.

But unfortunately, in this case, there is zero (0) performance improvement.

Can anyone help me understand why?

I measured both approaches on a core i7-4790 based machine.

UPDATE:

So I analyzed the generated machine code and determined that the MSFT VS2013 C++ compiler was generating the machine code such that the dependency chains of r1 and r2 could dispatch in parallel since Haswell has 2 FMA pipes.

r3 must dispatch after r1 so in this case, the second FMA pipe is idle.

I thought that if I unroll the loop to do 6 sets of FMAs instead of 3, then I could keep all the FMA pipes busy on every iteration.

Unfortunately, when I checked the assembly dump in this case, the MSFT compiler did not choose register assignments that would have allowed the type of parallel dispatch that I was looking for and I verified that I didn't get the performance increase that I was looking for.

Is there a way I can change my C code (using intrinsics) to enable the compiler to generate better code?

Comment: Yes, I think I tried something similar and got the same results - I also tried mixed FMA/AVX2 to see if there was any parallelism that could be exploited but again, no benefit.

Comment: I would not know even how to measure it.

Comment: If you're summing up something like a dot-product where the multiply is not on the critical path, FMAs will not help if you're latency-bound.

Comment: Isn't FMA for increased accuracy, not performance?

Comment: I don't see how the multiply is not on the critical path.  Please explain.

Comment: I once implemented Mandelbrot with FMA and AVX. There were no performance improvements on my Haswell system. FMA mainly increases accuracy and can decrease code size.

Comment: Did you check the ASM?  [gcc should compile both sources to use FMA instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34436233/fused-multiply-add-and-default-rounding-modes).  @R: FMA costs the same as a multiply, so the add part is basically free.  This is a big throughput win, esp. on pre-Skylake where FP add throughput is half of the FP mul throughput.

Comment: I did and the non-fma implementation only generated 1 fma instruction and the fma implementation generated many more fma instructions.  But I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: @R. - FMA is definitely for increased performance, primarily. That's how Intel and AMD positioned it, anyway and where most of the discussion has been directed. For throughput bounded oriented kernels, FMA potentially doubles their performance. It also allows the chip manufacturers to double their nominal GFLOPS ratings...

Comment: @fsasm, I see about a 15% performance improvement with FMA compared to AVX with Mandelbrot. It's not a factor of two but it's still significant. FMA in principle can double performance. It's not just about a single rounding mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't provide a full code sample that includes the surrounding loop (presumably there *is* a surrounding loop), so it is hard to answer definitively, but the main problem I see is that the latency of the dependency chains of your FMA code is considerably longer than your multiply + addition code.

Each of the three blocks in your FMA code is doing the same independent operation:

```
TOTAL += A1 * B1;
TOTAL += A2 * B2;
TOTAL += A3 * B3;
```

As it is structured, each operation depends on the previous due since each one reads and writes total. So the latency of this string of operation is 3 ops x 5 cycles/FMA = 15 cycles.

In your re-written version without FMA, the dependency chain on `TOTAL` is now broken, since you've done:

```
TOTAL_1 = A1 * B1;  # 1
TOTAL_2 = A2 * B2;  # 2
TOTAL_3 = A3 * B3;  # 3

TOTAL_1_2 = TOTAL_1 + TOTAL2;  # 5, depends on 1,2
TOTAL = TOTAL_1_2 + TOTAL3;    # 6, depends on 3,5
```

The first three MUL instructions can execute independently since they don't have any dependencies. The two add instructions are serially dependent on the multiplications. The latency of this sequence is thus 5 + 3 + 3 = 11.

So the latency of the second method is lower, even though it uses more CPU resources (5 total instructions issued). It is certainly possible then, that depending on how the overall loop is structured, that the lower latency cancels out the throughput advantages of FMA for this code - if it is at least partly latency bound.

For a more comprehensive static analysis, I highly recommend [Intel's IACA](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-architecture-code-analyzer) - which can take a loop iteration like the above, and tell you exactly what the bottleneck is, at least in the best case scenario. It can identify the critical paths in the loop, whether you are latency bound, etc.

Another possibility is that you are memory bound (latency or throughput), in which you'll also see similar behavior for FMA vs MUL + ADD.

Comment: Haswell has 5c FMA and mul, 3c add.  Broadwell has 5c FMA, 3c mul and add.  Skylake has 4c FMA/mul/add.   (Skylake drops the separate FP add unit and does all three in the FMA unit.  This doubles the add throughput.)    OP is on Haswell, so your answer correctly points out the latency win there.  Also, be careful with IACA.  You have to take its results with a grain of salt, because its uop counts for some instructions don't match Agner Fog's tables (or real life hardware, e.g. it thinks shld on SnB is 2 uops).  It's a great starting point, though.

Comment: What if you change the order of operations?  hmm, nope, can't come up with anything that lets an FMA be part of the add chain.  As usual, multiple accumulators are the way to keep more operations in flight.

Comment: Indeed. I've mostly found IACA to be accurate, and in at least one case where the results didn't match conventional wisdom (or Agner's guide, since updated), it was doing the right thing. The case I remember was for port 7 AGU operations,  where it correctly encoded the knowledge that only "simple" calculations (no index register) could be performed. A big problem with IACA is that it doesn't seem to be actively developed anymore, no updates since Haswell.

Comment: Yeah, I wish they'd open-source it or something if they're going to abandon it.  It'd be a shame if it just dies once future generations of CPUs are too different from Haswell for it to be useful.

Comment: @PeterCordes - yeah I can't see a way to use multiple accumulators with FMA here. As I mentioned, it's hard to say more without understanding the loop, but the key problem is that even though FMA has the same latency (5c on Haswell) as one of the other operations (MUL, also 5c on Haswell) - the fact that it bundles them together increases the dependency chains here. Usually that's not a problem since most kernels are throughput or memory bound, not dependency-chain latency bound.

Answer (score 1):

re: your edit:  Your code has three dependency chains (r1, r2, and r3), so it can keep three FMAs in flight at once.  FMA on Haswell is 5c latency, one per 0.5c throughput, so the machine can sustain 10 FMAs in flight.

If your code is in a loop, and the inputs to one iteration aren't generated by the previous iteration, then you could be getting 10 FMAs in flight that way.  (i.e. no loop-carried dependency chain involving the FMAs).  But since you don't see a perf gain, there's probably a dep chain causing throughput to be limited by latency.

---

You didn't post the ASM you're getting from MSVC, but you claim something about register assignments.  `xorps same,same` is [a recognized zeroing idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33668295/224132) that starts a new dependency chain, just like using a register as a write-only operand (e.g. the destination of a non-FMA AVX instruction.)

It's highly unlikely that the code could be correct but still contain a dependency of r3 on r1.  Make sure you understand that out-of-order execution with register renaming allows separate dependency chains to use the same register.

---

BTW, instead of  `__m256 r1 = _mm256_xor_ps (r1, r1);`, you should use `__m256 r1 = _mm256_setzero_ps();`.  You should avoid using the variable you're declaring in its own initializer!  Compilers sometimes make silly code when you use uninitialized vectors, e.g. loading garbage from stack memory, or doing an extra `xorps`.

Even better would be:

```
__m256 r1 = _mm256_mul_ps (rp1, m6);
r1 = _mm256_fmadd_ps (rp2, m7, r1);
r1 = _mm256_fmadd_ps (rp3, m8, r1);
```

This avoids needing an `xorps` to zero a reg for the accumulator.

On Broadwell, `mulps` has lower latency than FMA.

On Skylake, FMA/mul/add are all 4c latency, one per 0.5c throughput. They dropped the separate adder from port1 and do it on the FMA unit.  They shaved a cycle of latency off the FMA unit.

Comment: I do understand the register renaming mechanism.  However, that doesn't help you if you've got RAW dependencies.  My first attempt at unrolling the loop caused the compiler to generate exactly this so there was no way that multiple FMA instructions could dispatch in parallel.

Comment: @rohitsan: `xor r1,r1` starts a fresh dependency chain with a write-only zeroing operation, even though xor normally depends on its input operands.  Post the asm, because I don't believe your claim that the compiler made code where the FMAs for `r3` were part of the same dependency chain as `r1`, unless there's source code you didn't show.

Comment: I was not referring to the example code above.  I was referring to an unrolled version of the above code where I do 6 sets of similar FMA computations (dependency chains).

Comment: @rohitsan: So are `r1`, `r2`, and `r3` just separate accumulators that you will combine after the loop?  In that case, you'll get better results from not reusing the same accumulator inside the loop.  Anyway, sort out your dep chains so you can have lots of FMAs in flight and you should be fine.

Comment: Well, I tried creating 6 accumulators r1 through r6 and the hope was that the compiler would generate code to allow 2 of those accumulators to execute in parallel at different stages of the loop's body.  In this case, the number of loop iterations would (obviously) be cut in half.  However, I observed 0 performance improvement in this case.  I need to spend some time root causing why.  It would probably work out better for me to just write assembly language but I have been avoiding that for many reasons (code maintainability, etc.).

Comment: @rohitsan: you could write some asm for testing purposes to see what kind of asm the compiler needs to make.  Keep in mind you need to keep 10 FMAs in flight to saturate Haswell's 5c latency, one per 0.5c throughput FMA unit.  Once you have something that runs fast, write something similar in C to get the compiler to do that.