# Difference in gcc -ffp-contract options

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, compiler-optimization, fma

I have a question regarding the `-ffp-contract` flag in GNU GCC (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

The flag documentation is written as follows:

> `-ffp-contract=off` disables floating-point expression contraction. `-ffp-contract=fast` enables floating-point expression contraction such as forming of fused multiply-add operations if the target has native support for them. `-ffp-contract=on` enables floating-point expression contraction if allowed by the language standard. This is currently not implemented and treated equal to `-ffp-contract=off`. The default is `-ffp-contract=fast`.

Now the question:

- What is the difference between fast and on?
- Is there any other contraction example beside the FMA (or similar like the fused-mult sub)?

Comment: Since currently on=off, the difference is that fast does contraction while on doesn't...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C89, FP contraction is disallowed. Starting with C99, an implementation may do FP contraction of expressions by default, but would then be required to provide a `#pragma STDC FP_CONTRACT` ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/impl)) which can be toggled to influence contraction behavior.

So the GCC switch was **supposed** to be:

- `-ffp-contract=off`: Don't do contraction. Ignore `#pragma STDC FP_CONTRACT`. This is the default for `-std=c89`.
- `-ffp-contract=on`: Enable contraction by default and honor `#pragma STDC FP_CONTRACT`. This would be the default for `-std=c99` and above.
- **`-ffp-contract=fast`: This is the GCC default, even *without* any fast-math options.**  We don't claim ISO conformance in fast-math mode, so it's ok to always contract, even separate expressions (See Marc Glisse's comment).  This is the default for `-std=gnu99` and other GNU dialects of C.

Unfortunately, `#pragma STDC FP_CONTRACT` is *not* yet implemented in GCC, so for now **`gcc -ffp-contract=on` does** what is necessary to stay ISO-conforming: **nothing**.  i.e. on = off, because the only other behaviour GCC knows how to implement (fast) is too aggressive for `on`.

You'd have to dig into the sources (or mailing list) to see what kind of contractions GCC is able to do, but it doesn't have to be limited to FMA.

See [GCC and Clang on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6UzQHP) for a simple testcase of one expression vs. 2 statements.  **Clang defaults to `-ffp-contract=off`** but supports `on` and `fast`, as you can see.  GCC only supports `off` and `fast`, with `on` mapping to `off`.

---

What the C11 standard has to say about `#pragma STDC FP_CONTRACT`:

> **§6.5¶8**:  A floating expression may be contracted , that is, evaluated as
> though it were a single operation, thereby omitting rounding errors implied by the source code and the expression evaluation method.89) The FP_CONTRACT pragma in <math.h> provides a way to disallow contracted expressions. Otherwise, whether and how expressions are contracted is implementation-defined.90)
>
> 89. The intermediate operations in the contracted expression are evaluated as if to infinite range and precision, while the final operation is rounded to the format determined by the expression evaluation method. A contracted expression might also omit the raising of floating-point exceptions.
> 90. This license is specifically intended to allow implementations to exploit fast machine instructions that combine multiple C operators. As contractions potentially undermine predictability, and can even decrease accuracy for containing expressions, their use needs to be well-defined and clearly documented.

Comment: `a*a*a*a*a*a` is not treated as a contraction by gcc. Also, with everything implemented, "on" would optimize `x=2*x+3` to fma but "fast" would be required to contract `x*=2;x+=3` (not a single expression).

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thanks for the correction. I amended the answer.

Comment: GCC behaves like `-ffp-contract=fast` by default, even with `-fno-fast-math`.  https://godbolt.org/z/6UzQHP.

Comment: @PeterCordes -ffp-contract=fast is the default for -std=gnu17 but not for -std=c17 (the strict mode).

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Good point; I was just thinking in terms of the overall default because `-std=gnu(something)` is the default for that option.  Is this answer misleading now?

Comment: About `Clang defaults to -ffp-contract=off`. Clang's documentation says: `-ffp-contract=on (according to FP_CONTRACT pragma, default)`. `clang -cc1 --help | grep contract` says the same.

Comment: @pmor: clang `-O3 -march=skylake` doesn't contract `a*b+3` into an FMA even within a single statement, but it does with `-ffp-contract=on`  (bottom right output pane on https://godbolt.org/z/eW499xno4 vs. bottom left).  I tried clang 9.0 and clang nightly trunk, and a couple earlier versions.  So the behaviour with no extra options matches `-ffp-contract=off`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Interesting. Try to add `#pragma STDC FP_CONTRACT OFF` and see that gcc (9.2 and trunk) still contracts: `vfmadd213ss` is generated. Per C11, 7.12.2 `FP_CONTRACT OFF` _can be used_ (i.e. not _shall_) to "disallow the implementation to contract expressions".

Comment: @pmor: yeah, I guess current GCC doesn't support the pragma at all, only command line options.

Comment: @PeterCordes https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37845

Comment: @pmor: Yup, they decided that having `-std=c99` imply fp-contract=off (instead of the default gnu99 -> on) was sufficient to comply with the C standard, so closed the bug.  If you carefully read the comment at the bottom of the comment with the commit, https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37845#c6 , Vincent points out that that bug wasn't about lack of support for the pragma per-se, and that would be a separate enhancement request which someone could open.