# Floating-point operations with Clang and -O2. No compile-time optimization since version 14

Tags: c++, floating-point, compiler-optimization, clang++

After compiling and running my program with `clang14` I found a bug in my program that boils down to the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    double a = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
    double b = -0.1;
    double c = a * b - a * b;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

```
clang++-14 main.cpp -O2 && ./a.out
```

results in

```
-4.9896e+290
```

[godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIMxqkrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxHoADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/oFJKY4CoeFRLLHxXLaY9vkMQgRMxAQZPn4BFVVptfUEhZExcXoKdQ1NWa2DXT3FpRIAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMxhyN5YANQma25Og8SYrPvYJhoAguub25h7B7R4LIQK55c312EEOyxMYQgMz2AHYrNcdpCdugFtF6DsmI8ACI7QboEAgBg%2BOJ4ZAAfWerwI7wOMK8cMw5wx/1UQP24KuUOhsPh0WROwAtBoAHRcemfJlkik7ZDsxEAKh2bI5CJ2kui/IhULRGLQXl%2B%2BzcmpFjy1B1RBHRIFctEVNxBSI4c1onAArLw/BwtKRUJwtZZrKiFksHuseKQCJorXMANb%2BNbcgBsZltIOjXDWZkjINtGi4AA59JxJLwWBINDyC0Xi8Xyo7na6OLwFCBAoGnVbSHBYDBEChUCwEnQ4uRKGhO934ltDMApAXSFgAG64zAANTwmAA7gB5BKMTj%2Bmi0AhxGsQaJB0jRML1ACeG94x%2BYxFPy%2Bi2kwDgvpH7bEEy4YtHPDYnmH%2BRnEH98BOBw8EnTAax/TBVEfdUVmdH5KkPZ5omIM8PCwZ8CGIF4LzmKgDGABR5yXVd124Xh%2BEEEQxHYKQZEERQVHUH9dHKAwjBQaxrH0PBohrSA5lQBJqkgjllzMatKkfaoXAYdxPGaCRpBCMJehKfozFIXJUgEEY/HonTqkmPp4i0uwZI6IZGkUrIuECCzQIEToGhMjSzNsaz9PzTyJjUqZNLmBRvWWWYsw4e1SHLXhKx2VR00jDlI0kEUOOAHYpG5QsdggXBCBIPYzDWLgZl4estBmOYEFOLB4iBUgw0kSMow0ABOWNbXakENACNZbXCnNSDzEF015GMosPStq1rAMgzmZs2wWAgEnVXsIH7Lt6GICJWBWeLEuS1KRwy5rC14TB8CIHD0XKKjhFEcR6Lupi1EPNjSEXNCEjw8LIuil1OGXdUVt%2BVAqDihKkpS4cjAyyQsqynKPAHLbCuK0rZobSrSGqphasoa1s1zfwuG5dMUwmn8ptsGbyuDBqQEkQsNFtVnisjdNOvTTMbQ4NYHUmzgyrmptWwWiAkA2wc1qlraUDShM01/adlhIlc10dTc6B3Yg9wPH8rzPZ9DZvO8HyfCiXw7N8CA/L9Dywf9gEA51gMs8DIOdaDYJ3Q9EN550ULQm8MPgsqcLzCj8MI4iF3V8jN1kGjHukZ6lFe1j/H0EcuI9SxeP4%2BAhJEtIxIkqT2mcCBXG8swQSCeS3OmfqjLSWv69bgp/NMkB%2Bsc6oXJszIWnr/urL8ooe77rzbJH3zXO79ze6CkK6MJiKBapzgIYO6G0oyiMeS4HK8qutGSuFrHQxANYI1v%2B%2BH8fgbiZG7k67WdM2ttIrP/arT/upjWOsItxZICWiDGWHZNpxB2mwTg%2B0oY7GAMgUUXAzBv3OpdEgeAboMXurRZSeCXosWdLoLSn0mDfSjr9TeFZAbA3VDsMGO9EEw3SgmBGx8IDI2gcQNGZgMZ02xrjfG9VeaDTzGYUmIIkxcFahoSQcY5EKJGpTOhVYabAKvgzNYzVdEJXTE1Vq5NZE804PzNRMUhaYwquvSSQ18yBAAdYoRcxwK6zSIzIAA)

Why doesn't clang optimize code like this since version 14? Already at compile-time it turns out to be not zero.

Comment: Interestingly, if you make `a` and `b` `constexpr` you get `0` as the value of `c`.

Comment: clang14 did optimise, the result was calculated in compile time and stored in `.LCPI0_0`. But I guess it would take a language lawyer to tell which behaviour is correct (or maybe it's an implementation defined behaviour and one should look into clang documentation somewhere).

Comment: I assume this gets "optimized" at compile-time to `fma(a, b, -a*b)` which is not zero. Play around with different architectures and optimization options here: https://godbolt.org/z/7Ka5s8s59

Comment: @Yksisarvinen (I'm not a lawyer, but) I think compilers are allowed to calculate expressions with an overall higher precision than the input arguments -- this allows them to use `fma` (and it allowed to use x87 `long double` before SSE-math was standard)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [clang 14.0.0 floating point optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73985098/clang-14-0-0-floating-point-optimizations) - tl;dr: `-ffp-contract=off` can be used to turn off FMA, which then produces the same result as clang 13: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7KjhT6EhK)

Comment: If you're going to link to Godbolt, you have the asm right there.  If you write a function the returns a `double` it compiles to one instruction, very easy to see that it's not doing any FP math at run-time with either clang version.  https://godbolt.org/z/f89dE66nc 
 Unlike with `std::cout << c << '\n';` or much worse your `std::endl` where there's a whole bunch of asm burying the instruction that sets XMM0.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Comment: Fun fact: `-ffp-contract=` `off` or `fast` both return 0, only the clang14 default of `on` returns non-zero here.  @chtz: IIRC, the standard says temporaries within a single expression can be elided if computed with infinite precision, as in FMA, if `#pragma STDC FP_CONTRACT ON` is set ([Is floating point expression contraction allowed in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49278125)).  Being allowed to use higher precision temporaries is a separate part of the standard, `FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 2` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits/FLT_EVAL_METHOD .