# How to force GCC to generate specific floating-point instructions

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, riscv

Given the following C code,

```c
    double a = 4.00;
    double b = 123.456789;
    double c = 15.123;

    double res = a*b + c;

    return res;
```

compiling with `riscv64-linux-gcc -g -o2` generates the following

```
    double res = a*b + c;
   102e8:   fe843707            fld fa4,-24(s0)
   102ec:   fe043787            fld fa5,-32(s0)
   102f0:   12f777d3            fmul.d  fa5,fa4,fa5
   102f4:   fd843707            fld fa4,-40(s0)
   102f8:   02f777d3            fadd.d  fa5,fa4,fa5
   102fc:   fcf43827            fsd fa5,-48(s0)
```

Meaning that the compiler did not recognize that this is a fused multiplication/addition operation (`FMADD`).

So, I have two questions:

- Is there a means to force the compiler to generate `FMADD.D` instead of the separate `MUL.D` and `ADD.D` instructions?
- What mad the compiler choose to implement it this way?

(from what I know, `FMA` is generally more efficient that separate `MUL` and `ADD`, and also, 1 instruction is generally more efficient than 2 from a power and speed point of view, so I'm a little bit confused about the choices being made by GCC)

Comment: Well, first of all, you could check the macro FP_FAST_FMA (in math.h). This will at least tell you whether or not GCC would consider FMA to actually be faster that MUL/ADD on your platform. And if it is, you could use the fma() function instead (which hopefully will cause the compiler to emit an FMA instruction)

Comment: There's the `fma()` library function which GCC knows how to inline when an FMA instruction is available.  Did you enable optimization?  It looks like no, or GCC would have done constant-propagation.  GCC might have done FP contraction on that expression even at `-O0` but chose not to look for it.  `-o2` sets the output filename to `2`.  GCC does default to FP_CONTRACT enabled, even across expressions.

Comment: Yup, with optimization enabled we get contraction of `a*b+c` into FMA, for a function that takes args (so constant-propagation can't just turn it into a load of the answer): https://godbolt.org/z/wHpCxZ

Comment: You may also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352510/difference-in-gcc-ffp-contract-options

Comment: @PeterCordes ow, my bad, it's was due to the -o flag. Correcting to -O produced the FMADD instruction. Thanks!