# Is it legit for `+=` and `+` to give different answers for the same `float` operands in C?

Tags: c, floating-point

My understanding is that in C,

- `float` addition and multiplication [are deterministic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7366183/94977); and
- `A += B` should behave like `A = A + B` when A has no side-effects.

But then, why does the assertion in this program fail?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

void trial(long long i, float *src, float *target, float g) {
  float a = target[i];
  float x = g * src[i];
  printf("%g %g %g\n", a, x, a + x);
  target[i] += g * src[i];
  assert(target[i] == a + x);
}

int main() {
  float target[2] = { 0.0, -4.52271e-06 };
  float src[2] = { -0.000926437, -0.00102722 };

  trial(1, src, target, 0.01235);
  return 0;
}
```

Try it yourself: [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/37fs6YT75), [git repo](https://github.com/jorendorff/c-float-assertion)

It does fail, on x86 with enough SSE instructions enabled. I compiled with `clang -O2 -march=native -Wall -o test test.c` and the output is:

```
-4.52271e-06 -1.26862e-05 -1.72089e-05
test: test.c:9: void trial(long long, float *, float *, float): Assertion `target[i] == a + x' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The assertion fails in GCC, too. In Clang, it fails even with `-O0`!

Looking at the assembly, I think the compiler emits a fused multiply-add instruction for `+=` but not for `+`. Perhaps this instruction does not round the result of multiplication to the nearest `float` value.

**Is this legit?** That is, does the C standard allow this behavior? As far as I can tell, the latest [draft standard for C](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3096.pdf) specifies in Annex F that implementations supporting IEC standard floating-point arithmetic must implement `float` addition and multiplication according to that standard, which is deterministic. I don't see where C allows a rounding operation to be optimized away.

Comment: Not sure about C, but in C++ compilers frequently [hand-wave around floating point arithmetic](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath) unless you explicitly ask otherwise (and sometimes even if you do, actually). E.g. they may store 64-bit `double` in a 80-bit register, altering the result _sometimes_. E.g. GCC [does not accept floating-point-related bug reports](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/#nonbugs_general).

Comment: My own assumption in C++ (and any other high-level programming language, frankly) is that floating-point arithmetic is actually _non-deterministic_. I've seen code simple as "take square root, round down to `int`" failing.

Comment: If you're looking for authoritative answers based on what the C standard allow, you may wish to tag this question [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer)

Comment: MSVC the assertion does not fail (is not caught).

Comment: you are using an equals comparison on float.

Comment: I dont get an assert()

Comment: @old_timer That's intentional and the point. The question is whether the C standard allows the program to compute those numbers differently.

Comment: https://www.phys.uconn.edu/~rozman/Courses/P2200_15F/downloads/floating-point-guide-2015-10-15.pdf

Comment: clang and gcc behave the same way, no assert.

Comment: the math is the same, you can test for that, and perhaps have.  looks like something to do with the assert?

Comment: @old_timer I think you're still missing the point. This is a question about what optimizations _the C standard allows_ for floating point arithmetic. That link isn't really relevant. Also, are you sure you're running the right code? clang 3.2 through trunk and GCC 4.4.7 through trunk _all_ fail the assert for x86-64 on godbolt.

Comment: Looked at the math and the results for each code path and this all looks good, it is behaving as expected despite using an equal/not equal comparison on float.  (which is what you are trying to prove is in theory acceptable in this use case).

Comment: this code, as written is not testing + and +=, there are other factors in play here, If you want to isolate it then you need more code than above.  you are trying to compare a multiply and accumulate with separate multiple and add instructions, which can be separate floating point instructions and can give different results.  to test multiply and accumulate with separate multiply then add later, make a test for that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Extra Precision

> - `float` addition and multiplication [are deterministic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7366183/94977);

This is false. The answer you link to states that “floating-point” is deterministic and clarifies that “The same floating-point operations, run on the same hardware, always produces the same result.” However, the C and C++ standards do not require C and C++ implementations to always use “The same floating-point operations.” So `float` arithmetic is not deterministic in this sense.

> - `A += B` should behave like `A = A + B` when A has no side-effects.

Yes, `A += B` behaves like `A = A + B` except that the lvalue `A` is evaluated only once. However, the C standard does not require that `A = A + B` have a deterministic behavior. In particular, `A = A + B*C;` is allowed to give two different results in two different instances.

Specifically, C 2018 5.2.4.2.2 10 says:

> …  the values yielded by operators with floating operands … and of floating constants are evaluated to a format whose range and precision may be greater than required by the type.

Consider `target[i] += g * src[i];`. The C implementation may implement this by performing a `float` multiplication of `g` by `src[i]` and a `float` addition of that product to `target[i]`. However, due to the permission above, it is also allowed to implement this by performing a `double` multiplication of `g` by `src[i]` and a `double` addition of that product to `target[i]`. Or it could implement it with an effectively infinitely precise multiplication and an infinitely precise addition.

The standard leaves it up to the implementation to make this choice. It provides a method for the implementation to report some information about the choice it makes; the value of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` defined in `<float.h>` is one of:

- 0, meaning all floating-point operations are performed in their nominal types,
- 1, meaning all `float` and `double` operations are performed in `double`, and `long double` is performed in `long double`,
- 2, meaning all floating-point operations are performed in `long double`, or
- −1, meaning the implementation does not assert how floating-point operations are performed.

In your case, it appears the compiler used a fused multiply-add instruction for `target[i] += g * src[i];`, which is equivalent to performing the operations with infinitely precise arithmetic and rounding the result to `float`.

Note that the extended precision cannot be carried indefinitely. A fuller quote from 5.2.4.2.2 10 is:

> Except for assignment and cast (which remove all extra range and precision), the values yielded by operators with floating operands and values subject to the usual arithmetic conversions and of floating constants are evaluated to a format whose range and precision may be greater than required by the type.

Thus, whenever an assignment or cast is performed, the value must be converted to its nominal type.

Thus, for your `float x = g * src[i];` followed by `a + x`, the compiler cannot use a fused multiply-add, because the `g * src[i]` product must be converted to the `float` precision when assigned to `x`; the extra precision cannot be carried through to `a + x`.

The C++ standard has substantially equivalent text.

### Contraction

C 2018 6.5 8 says:

> A floating expression may be *contracted*, that is, evaluated as though it were a single operation, thereby omitting rounding errors implied by the source code and the expression evaluation method…

This means that even if `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`, discussed above, is 0 and `float` arithmetic is performed only with `float` precision, the processor may perform `a = b + c*d` using a fused multiply-add instruction, which calculates as if there were no rounding error in `c*d` when it is added to `b`. 6.5 8 allows other forms of contractions, but fused multiply-add and fused multiply-subtract are the most common.

C 2018 7.12.2 specifies an `FP_CONTRACT` pragma, so that, if a translation unit has `#include <math.h>` and `#pragma STDC FP_CONTRACT OFF`, the compiler should not use contractions. (Note that getting a compiler to obey this and other rules of the C standard may require using certain switches, such as using `-std=c18` with GCC or Clang to request better conformance to the standard than their default behavior.)

An alternate way to avoid contractions and extra precision is to use assignments or casts with single floating-point operations, such as:

```
float t0 = c*d;
a = b + t0;
```

or:

```
a = b + (float) (c*d);
```

Technically, the wording in the standard still permits the above to be performed with extra precision and then rounded to `float`. This can cause double-rounding errors. However, it would be inefficient for a compiler to calculate a single operation using `double` arithmetic and then use another instruction to round it to `float`, so a compiler with optimization enabled should use only `float` arithmetic to evaluate such expressions.

Also note the use of contractions forces a sort of non-determinism on the evaluation of floating-point arithmetic. In `y = a*b + c*d`, the compiler can use a fused multiply-add to add one of the products without rounding, but it cannot do that for both. Which one will it choose? The answer is likely deterministic for any particular expression, but when `a*b + c*d` appears as a subexpression in a larger expression, we generally cannot be sure which one the compiler will choose to incorporate with a fused multiply-add.

### Lack of Accuracy

C 2018 5.2.4.2.2 7 says:

> The accuracy of the floating-point operations (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`) and of the library functions in `<math.h>` and `<complex.h>` that return floating-point results is implementation-defined,…

It is not clear this passage allows any form of non-determinism. Maybe it means that, while the accuracy is implementation-defined, it must be some specific accuracy that is always reproduced by the C implementation. Modern hardware largely conforms to IEEE 754, which the notable exception of handling of subnormal numbers. So this passage may be largely a nod to two things:

- When the compiler evaluates floating-point expressions at compile time, it might use more precision than at run time.
- Software implementations of floating-point arithmetic, intended to support C floating-point on hardware without floating-point instructions, might provide less than *correctly rounded* (the term for rounding exactly as specified by the IEEE 754 standard) accuracy.

In any case, the sentence is vague enough that we cannot be sure floating-point expressions in C will always return the same results given the same inputs.

Comment: If the compiler has this behavior but also defines `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` to be `0`, can that be compliant?

Comment: @JasonOrendorff: Yes, there is more flexibility in the C standard for floating-point arithmetic than just 5.2.4.2.2 10. 6.5 8 allows floating-point operations to be contacted, meaning `a+b*c` can be made into a fused multiply-add. There is a pragma for turning that off.

Comment: `#pragma STDC FP_CONTRACT OFF` prevents [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/qenTqv5Md) from emitting a fused multiply-add instruction, but not [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/Ys1r5h7va), which still flunks the assertion. Both compilers define `__STDC_IEC_559__` on x86-64 and both define `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` to be `0`.

Comment: Oh, OK, it appears that the default GCC compiler options are non-compliant, even without `-ffast-math`, but if you ask for a standard mode like `-std=c17`, or explicitly say `-ffp-contract=off`, GCC does not perform this optimization and is compliant. See <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352510/difference-in-gcc-ffp-contract-options>. Thanks for the fantastic answer, Eric.

Comment: "Lack of accuracy": I think the intent must have been to require correctly rounded answers, i.e. 5.2.4.2.2 7 is moot in implementations that claim IEC 60559 compliance. Annex F says: "Where a binding between the C language and IEC 60559 is indicated, the IEC 60559-specified behavior is adopted by reference, unless stated otherwise." Now, arguably 5.2.4.2.2 7 _does_ state otherwise; but it would then do so for all operations, and in that case, the quoted sentence does nothing! That can't be the intent. ...But I agree the standard is vague. :-\