# -O1 alters floating point math

Tags: c++, gcc, floating-point

The following `c++` program gives a numerically different result when compiled with `-O0` or `-O1`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
  std::array<double, 2> v;
  v.fill(0);

  std::get<0>(v) = 0x1.5b4d3afe1f7d2p-1;
  double theta = 0x1.1aef12f82caf9p+2;

  double c = std::cos(theta);
  double s = std::sin(theta);
  double vi = c * std::get<0>(v) - s * std::get<1>(v);
  double vj = s * std::get<0>(v) + c * std::get<1>(v);
  std::get<0>(v) = vi;
  std::get<1>(v) = vj;

  std::cout << std::hexfloat;
  for (const auto& x : v)
    std::cout << x << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I am using `gcc` 9.2.0. I employ `std::hexfloat` to be sure to print out `double` variables with full precision.

Compiling with

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -pedantic -O0 -o test test.cpp
```

gives the following result (bold mine)

```
-0x1.8f4e436eb5371p-3 -0x1.4ca54aa5d4e1ep-1
```

With

```
 g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -pedantic -O1 -o test test.cpp
```

the output is

```
-0x1.8f4e436eb5372p-3 -0x1.4ca54aa5d4e1ep-1
```

The difference between the optimizations flags enabled by `-O0` and `-O1` that I can extract with `-Q --help=optimizers` are as follows

```
$ g++ -O0 -Q --help=optimizers >optO0.txt
$ g++ -O1 -Q --help=optimizers >optO1.txt
$ diff optO0.txt optO1.txt|grep ^'>'
>   -fbranch-count-reg                          [enabled]
>   -fcombine-stack-adjustments                 [enabled]
>   -fcompare-elim                              [enabled]
>   -fcprop-registers                           [enabled]
>   -fdefer-pop                                 [enabled]
>   -fforward-propagate                         [enabled]
>   -fguess-branch-probability                  [enabled]
>   -fif-conversion                             [enabled]
>   -fif-conversion2                            [enabled]
>   -finline-functions-called-once      [enabled]
>   -fipa-profile                               [enabled]
>   -fipa-pure-const                            [enabled]
>   -fipa-reference                             [enabled]
>   -fipa-reference-addressable                 [enabled]
>   -fmove-loop-invariants                      [enabled]
>   -fomit-frame-pointer                        [enabled]
>   -freorder-blocks                            [enabled]
>   -fshrink-wrap                               [enabled]
>   -fsplit-wide-types                          [enabled]
>   -fssa-phiopt                                [enabled]
>   -ftree-bit-ccp                              [enabled]
>   -ftree-builtin-call-dce                     [enabled]
>   -ftree-ccp                                  [enabled]
>   -ftree-ch                                   [enabled]
>   -ftree-coalesce-vars                        [enabled]
>   -ftree-copy-prop                            [enabled]
>   -ftree-dce                                  [enabled]
>   -ftree-dominator-opts                       [enabled]
>   -ftree-dse                                  [enabled]
>   -ftree-fre                                  [enabled]
>   -ftree-pta                                  [enabled]
>   -ftree-sink                                 [enabled]
>   -ftree-slsr                                 [enabled]
>   -ftree-sra                                  [enabled]
>   -ftree-ter                                  [enabled]
```

According to this list, as well as to the man page of `gcc`, `-O1` does not enable optimization flags that alters floating point math, like `-ffast-math` , so why does the output differ?

**Edit:**

Using the flag `-ffloat-store` as suggested in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7517877/8769985) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7517588/8769985) does not change the results.

C library version is

```
$ ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.30
```

The library is installed from the package `glibc 2.30-1` of Arch Linux. Architecture is x86_64.

This is the assembler dump for the `-O0` case (obtained with `g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -pedantic -O0 -S -o test test.cpp`)

```
.file   "test.cpp"
    .text
    .section    .text._ZStanSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_,"axG",@progbits,_ZStanSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_,comdat
    .weak   _ZStanSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_
    .type   _ZStanSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_, @function
_ZStanSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_:
.LFB1415:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -8(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    andl    -8(%rbp), %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1415:
    .size   _ZStanSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_, .-_ZStanSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_
    .section    .text._ZStorSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_,"axG",@progbits,_ZStorSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_,comdat
    .weak   _ZStorSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_
    .type   _ZStorSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_, @function
_ZStorSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_:
.LFB1416:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -8(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    orl -8(%rbp), %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1416:
    .size   _ZStorSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_, .-_ZStorSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_
    .section    .text._ZStcoSt13_Ios_Fmtflags,"axG",@progbits,_ZStcoSt13_Ios_Fmtflags,comdat
    .weak   _ZStcoSt13_Ios_Fmtflags
    .type   _ZStcoSt13_Ios_Fmtflags, @function
_ZStcoSt13_Ios_Fmtflags:
.LFB1418:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    notl    %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1418:
    .size   _ZStcoSt13_Ios_Fmtflags, .-_ZStcoSt13_Ios_Fmtflags
    .section    .text._ZStoRRSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_,"axG",@progbits,_ZStoRRSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_,comdat
    .weak   _ZStoRRSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_
    .type   _ZStoRRSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_, @function
_ZStoRRSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_:
.LFB1419:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -12(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    (%rax), %eax
    movl    -12(%rbp), %edx
    movl    %edx, %esi
    movl    %eax, %edi
    call    _ZStorSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
    movl    %eax, (%rdx)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1419:
    .size   _ZStoRRSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_, .-_ZStoRRSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_
    .section    .text._ZStaNRSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_,"axG",@progbits,_ZStaNRSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_,comdat
    .weak   _ZStaNRSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_
    .type   _ZStaNRSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_, @function
_ZStaNRSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_:
.LFB1420:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -12(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    (%rax), %eax
    movl    -12(%rbp), %edx
    movl    %edx, %esi
    movl    %eax, %edi
    call    _ZStanSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
    movl    %eax, (%rdx)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1420:
    .size   _ZStaNRSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_, .-_ZStaNRSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_
    .section    .text._ZNSt8ios_base4setfESt13_Ios_FmtflagsS0_,"axG",@progbits,_ZNSt8ios_base4setfESt13_Ios_FmtflagsS0_,comdat
    .align 2
    .weak   _ZNSt8ios_base4setfESt13_Ios_FmtflagsS0_
    .type   _ZNSt8ios_base4setfESt13_Ios_FmtflagsS0_, @function
_ZNSt8ios_base4setfESt13_Ios_FmtflagsS0_:
.LFB1449:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $32, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, -24(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -28(%rbp)
    movl    %edx, -32(%rbp)
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    movl    24(%rax), %eax
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -32(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %edi
    call    _ZStcoSt13_Ios_Fmtflags
    movl    %eax, %edx
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    addq    $24, %rax
    movl    %edx, %esi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZStaNRSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_
    movl    -32(%rbp), %edx
    movl    -28(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %edx, %esi
    movl    %eax, %edi
    call    _ZStanSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_
    movl    %eax, %edx
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    addq    $24, %rax
    movl    %edx, %esi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZStoRRSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1449:
    .size   _ZNSt8ios_base4setfESt13_Ios_FmtflagsS0_, .-_ZNSt8ios_base4setfESt13_Ios_FmtflagsS0_
    .section    .text._ZSt8hexfloatRSt8ios_base,"axG",@progbits,_ZSt8hexfloatRSt8ios_base,comdat
    .weak   _ZSt8hexfloatRSt8ios_base
    .type   _ZSt8hexfloatRSt8ios_base, @function
_ZSt8hexfloatRSt8ios_base:
.LFB1481:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movl    $256, %esi
    movl    $4, %edi
    call    _ZStorSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_
    movl    %eax, %ecx
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    $260, %edx
    movl    %ecx, %esi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZNSt8ios_base4setfESt13_Ios_FmtflagsS0_
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1481:
    .size   _ZSt8hexfloatRSt8ios_base, .-_ZSt8hexfloatRSt8ios_base
    .local  _ZStL8__ioinit
    .comm   _ZStL8__ioinit,1,1
    .section    .rodata
.LC3:
    .string " "
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB2816:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    addq    $-128, %rsp
    movq    %fs:40, %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, -112(%rbp)
    leaq    -112(%rbp), %rdx
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rdx, %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE4fillERKd
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZSt3getILm0EdLm2EERT0_RSt5arrayIS0_XT1_EE
    movsd   .LC1(%rip), %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, (%rax)
    movsd   .LC2(%rip), %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, -96(%rbp)
    movq    -96(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %xmm0
    call    cos@PLT
    movq    %xmm0, %rax
    movq    %rax, -88(%rbp)
    movq    -96(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %xmm0
    call    sin@PLT
    movq    %xmm0, %rax
    movq    %rax, -80(%rbp)
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZSt3getILm0EdLm2EERT0_RSt5arrayIS0_XT1_EE
    movsd   (%rax), %xmm0
    mulsd   -88(%rbp), %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, -120(%rbp)
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZSt3getILm1EdLm2EERT0_RSt5arrayIS0_XT1_EE
    movsd   (%rax), %xmm0
    mulsd   -80(%rbp), %xmm0
    movsd   -120(%rbp), %xmm1
    subsd   %xmm0, %xmm1
    movapd  %xmm1, %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, -72(%rbp)
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZSt3getILm0EdLm2EERT0_RSt5arrayIS0_XT1_EE
    movsd   (%rax), %xmm0
    mulsd   -80(%rbp), %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, -120(%rbp)
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZSt3getILm1EdLm2EERT0_RSt5arrayIS0_XT1_EE
    movsd   (%rax), %xmm0
    mulsd   -88(%rbp), %xmm0
    addsd   -120(%rbp), %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, -64(%rbp)
    movsd   -72(%rbp), %xmm3
    movsd   %xmm3, -120(%rbp)
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZSt3getILm0EdLm2EERT0_RSt5arrayIS0_XT1_EE
    movsd   -120(%rbp), %xmm3
    movsd   %xmm3, (%rax)
    movsd   -64(%rbp), %xmm4
    movsd   %xmm4, -120(%rbp)
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZSt3getILm1EdLm2EERT0_RSt5arrayIS0_XT1_EE
    movsd   -120(%rbp), %xmm4
    movsd   %xmm4, (%rax)
    leaq    _ZSt8hexfloatRSt8ios_base(%rip), %rsi
    leaq    _ZSt4cout(%rip), %rdi
    call    _ZNSolsEPFRSt8ios_baseS0_E@PLT
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, -56(%rbp)
    movq    -56(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE5beginEv
    movq    %rax, -104(%rbp)
    movq    -56(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE3endEv
    movq    %rax, -48(%rbp)
.L17:
    movq    -104(%rbp), %rax
    cmpq    -48(%rbp), %rax
    je  .L16
    movq    -104(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, -40(%rbp)
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rax
    movq    (%rax), %rax
    movq    %rax, %xmm0
    leaq    _ZSt4cout(%rip), %rdi
    call    _ZNSolsEd@PLT
    leaq    .LC3(%rip), %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc@PLT
    addq    $8, -104(%rbp)
    jmp .L17
.L16:
    movq    _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    leaq    _ZSt4cout(%rip), %rdi
    call    _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E@PLT
    movl    $0, %eax
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rcx
    xorq    %fs:40, %rcx
    je  .L19
    call    __stack_chk_fail@PLT
.L19:
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE2816:
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .text._ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE4fillERKd,"axG",@progbits,_ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE4fillERKd,comdat
    .align 2
    .weak   _ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE4fillERKd
    .type   _ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE4fillERKd, @function
_ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE4fillERKd:
.LFB3128:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    pushq   %rbx
    subq    $24, %rsp
    .cfi_offset 3, -24
    movq    %rdi, -24(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -32(%rbp)
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZNKSt5arrayIdLm2EE4sizeEv
    movq    %rax, %rbx
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE5beginEv
    movq    %rax, %rcx
    movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdx
    movq    %rbx, %rsi
    movq    %rcx, %rdi
    call    _ZSt6fill_nIPdmdET_S1_T0_RKT1_
    nop
    addq    $24, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE3128:
    .size   _ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE4fillERKd, .-_ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE4fillERKd
    .section    .text._ZSt3getILm0EdLm2EERT0_RSt5arrayIS0_XT1_EE,"axG",@progbits,_ZSt3getILm0EdLm2EERT0_RSt5arrayIS0_XT1_EE,comdat
    .weak   _ZSt3getILm0EdLm2EERT0_RSt5arrayIS0_XT1_EE
    .type   _ZSt3getILm0EdLm2EERT0_RSt5arrayIS0_XT1_EE, @function
_ZSt3getILm0EdLm2EERT0_RSt5arrayIS0_XT1_EE:
.LFB3129:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    $0, %esi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZNSt14__array_traitsIdLm2EE6_S_refERA2_Kdm
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE3129:
    .size   _ZSt3getILm0EdLm2EERT0_RSt5arrayIS0_XT1_EE, .-_ZSt3getILm0EdLm2EERT0_RSt5arrayIS0_XT1_EE
    .section    .text._ZSt3getILm1EdLm2EERT0_RSt5arrayIS0_XT1_EE,"axG",@progbits,_ZSt3getILm1EdLm2EERT0_RSt5arrayIS0_XT1_EE,comdat
    .weak   _ZSt3getILm1EdLm2EERT0_RSt5arrayIS0_XT1_EE
    .type   _ZSt3getILm1EdLm2EERT0_RSt5arrayIS0_XT1_EE, @function
_ZSt3getILm1EdLm2EERT0_RSt5arrayIS0_XT1_EE:
.LFB3130:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    $1, %esi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZNSt14__array_traitsIdLm2EE6_S_refERA2_Kdm
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE3130:
    .size   _ZSt3getILm1EdLm2EERT0_RSt5arrayIS0_XT1_EE, .-_ZSt3getILm1EdLm2EERT0_RSt5arrayIS0_XT1_EE
    .section    .text._ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE5beginEv,"axG",@progbits,_ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE5beginEv,comdat
    .align 2
    .weak   _ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE5beginEv
    .type   _ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE5beginEv, @function
_ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE5beginEv:
.LFB3132:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE4dataEv
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE3132:
    .size   _ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE5beginEv, .-_ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE5beginEv
    .section    .text._ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE3endEv,"axG",@progbits,_ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE3endEv,comdat
    .align 2
    .weak   _ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE3endEv
    .type   _ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE3endEv, @function
_ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE3endEv:
.LFB3133:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE4dataEv
    addq    $16, %rax
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE3133:
    .size   _ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE3endEv, .-_ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE3endEv
    .section    .text._ZNKSt5arrayIdLm2EE4sizeEv,"axG",@progbits,_ZNKSt5arrayIdLm2EE4sizeEv,comdat
    .align 2
    .weak   _ZNKSt5arrayIdLm2EE4sizeEv
    .type   _ZNKSt5arrayIdLm2EE4sizeEv, @function
_ZNKSt5arrayIdLm2EE4sizeEv:
.LFB3247:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movl    $2, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE3247:
    .size   _ZNKSt5arrayIdLm2EE4sizeEv, .-_ZNKSt5arrayIdLm2EE4sizeEv
    .section    .text._ZSt6fill_nIPdmdET_S1_T0_RKT1_,"axG",@progbits,_ZSt6fill_nIPdmdET_S1_T0_RKT1_,comdat
    .weak   _ZSt6fill_nIPdmdET_S1_T0_RKT1_
    .type   _ZSt6fill_nIPdmdET_S1_T0_RKT1_, @function
_ZSt6fill_nIPdmdET_S1_T0_RKT1_:
.LFB3248:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $32, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    movq    %rdx, -24(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZSt12__niter_baseIPdET_S1_
    movq    %rax, %rcx
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    movq    %rcx, %rdi
    call    _ZSt10__fill_n_aIPdmdEN9__gnu_cxx11__enable_ifIXsrSt11__is_scalarIT1_E7__valueET_E6__typeES6_T0_RKS4_
    movq    %rax, %rdx
    leaq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rdx, %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZSt12__niter_wrapIPdET_RKS1_S1_
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE3248:
    .size   _ZSt6fill_nIPdmdET_S1_T0_RKT1_, .-_ZSt6fill_nIPdmdET_S1_T0_RKT1_
    .section    .text._ZNSt14__array_traitsIdLm2EE6_S_refERA2_Kdm,"axG",@progbits,_ZNSt14__array_traitsIdLm2EE6_S_refERA2_Kdm,comdat
    .weak   _ZNSt14__array_traitsIdLm2EE6_S_refERA2_Kdm
    .type   _ZNSt14__array_traitsIdLm2EE6_S_refERA2_Kdm, @function
_ZNSt14__array_traitsIdLm2EE6_S_refERA2_Kdm:
.LFB3249:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
    leaq    0(,%rax,8), %rdx
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    addq    %rdx, %rax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE3249:
    .size   _ZNSt14__array_traitsIdLm2EE6_S_refERA2_Kdm, .-_ZNSt14__array_traitsIdLm2EE6_S_refERA2_Kdm
    .section    .text._ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE4dataEv,"axG",@progbits,_ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE4dataEv,comdat
    .align 2
    .weak   _ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE4dataEv
    .type   _ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE4dataEv, @function
_ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE4dataEv:
.LFB3250:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZNSt14__array_traitsIdLm2EE6_S_ptrERA2_Kd
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE3250:
    .size   _ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE4dataEv, .-_ZNSt5arrayIdLm2EE4dataEv
    .section    .text._ZSt12__niter_baseIPdET_S1_,"axG",@progbits,_ZSt12__niter_baseIPdET_S1_,comdat
    .weak   _ZSt12__niter_baseIPdET_S1_
    .type   _ZSt12__niter_baseIPdET_S1_, @function
_ZSt12__niter_baseIPdET_S1_:
.LFB3318:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE3318:
    .size   _ZSt12__niter_baseIPdET_S1_, .-_ZSt12__niter_baseIPdET_S1_
    .section    .text._ZSt10__fill_n_aIPdmdEN9__gnu_cxx11__enable_ifIXsrSt11__is_scalarIT1_E7__valueET_E6__typeES6_T0_RKS4_,"axG",@progbits,_ZSt10__fill_n_aIPdmdEN9__gnu_cxx11__enable_ifIXsrSt11__is_scalarIT1_E7__valueET_E6__typeES6_T0_RKS4_,comdat
    .weak   _ZSt10__fill_n_aIPdmdEN9__gnu_cxx11__enable_ifIXsrSt11__is_scalarIT1_E7__valueET_E6__typeES6_T0_RKS4_
    .type   _ZSt10__fill_n_aIPdmdEN9__gnu_cxx11__enable_ifIXsrSt11__is_scalarIT1_E7__valueET_E6__typeES6_T0_RKS4_, @function
_ZSt10__fill_n_aIPdmdEN9__gnu_cxx11__enable_ifIXsrSt11__is_scalarIT1_E7__valueET_E6__typeES6_T0_RKS4_:
.LFB3319:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movq    %rdi, -24(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -32(%rbp)
    movq    %rdx, -40(%rbp)
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rax
    movsd   (%rax), %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, -8(%rbp)
    movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
.L41:
    cmpq    $0, -16(%rbp)
    je  .L40
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    movsd   -8(%rbp), %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, (%rax)
    subq    $1, -16(%rbp)
    addq    $8, -24(%rbp)
    jmp .L41
.L40:
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE3319:
    .size   _ZSt10__fill_n_aIPdmdEN9__gnu_cxx11__enable_ifIXsrSt11__is_scalarIT1_E7__valueET_E6__typeES6_T0_RKS4_, .-_ZSt10__fill_n_aIPdmdEN9__gnu_cxx11__enable_ifIXsrSt11__is_scalarIT1_E7__valueET_E6__typeES6_T0_RKS4_
    .section    .text._ZSt12__niter_wrapIPdET_RKS1_S1_,"axG",@progbits,_ZSt12__niter_wrapIPdET_RKS1_S1_,comdat
    .weak   _ZSt12__niter_wrapIPdET_RKS1_S1_
    .type   _ZSt12__niter_wrapIPdET_RKS1_S1_, @function
_ZSt12__niter_wrapIPdET_RKS1_S1_:
.LFB3320:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE3320:
    .size   _ZSt12__niter_wrapIPdET_RKS1_S1_, .-_ZSt12__niter_wrapIPdET_RKS1_S1_
    .section    .text._ZNSt14__array_traitsIdLm2EE6_S_ptrERA2_Kd,"axG",@progbits,_ZNSt14__array_traitsIdLm2EE6_S_ptrERA2_Kd,comdat
    .weak   _ZNSt14__array_traitsIdLm2EE6_S_ptrERA2_Kd
    .type   _ZNSt14__array_traitsIdLm2EE6_S_ptrERA2_Kd, @function
_ZNSt14__array_traitsIdLm2EE6_S_ptrERA2_Kd:
.LFB3321:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE3321:
    .size   _ZNSt14__array_traitsIdLm2EE6_S_ptrERA2_Kd, .-_ZNSt14__array_traitsIdLm2EE6_S_ptrERA2_Kd
    .text
    .type   _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii, @function
_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii:
.LFB3455:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -8(%rbp)
    cmpl    $1, -4(%rbp)
    jne .L49
    cmpl    $65535, -8(%rbp)
    jne .L49
    leaq    _ZStL8__ioinit(%rip), %rdi
    call    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev@PLT
    leaq    __dso_handle(%rip), %rdx
    leaq    _ZStL8__ioinit(%rip), %rsi
    movq    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    __cxa_atexit@PLT
.L49:
    nop
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE3455:
    .size   _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii, .-_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii
    .type   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, @function
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
.LFB3456:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $65535, %esi
    movl    $1, %edi
    call    _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE3456:
    .size   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, .-_GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .section    .init_array,"aw"
    .align 8
    .quad   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .section    .rodata
    .align 8
.LC1:
    .long   2950821842
    .long   1072018643
    .align 8
.LC2:
    .long   797100793
    .long   1074900721
    .hidden __dso_handle
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 9.2.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

The assembler dump when using `-O1` (`g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -pedantic -O1 -S -o test test.cpp`) is

```
    .file   "test.cpp"
    .text
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC1:
    .string " "
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB2853:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 3, -16
    leaq    _ZSt4cout(%rip), %rbx
    movq    _ZSt4cout(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rbx, %rcx
    addq    -24(%rax), %rcx
    orl $260, 24(%rcx)
    movsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
    call    _ZNSo9_M_insertIdEERSoT_@PLT
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    movl    $1, %edx
    leaq    .LC1(%rip), %rsi
    call    _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l@PLT
    movsd   .LC2(%rip), %xmm0
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
    call    _ZNSo9_M_insertIdEERSoT_@PLT
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    movl    $1, %edx
    leaq    .LC1(%rip), %rsi
    call    _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l@PLT
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
    call    _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_@PLT
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE2853:
    .size   main, .-main
    .type   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, @function
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
.LFB3477:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    leaq    _ZStL8__ioinit(%rip), %rdi
    call    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev@PLT
    leaq    __dso_handle(%rip), %rdx
    leaq    _ZStL8__ioinit(%rip), %rsi
    movq    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rdi
    call    __cxa_atexit@PLT
    addq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE3477:
    .size   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, .-_GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .section    .init_array,"aw"
    .align 8
    .quad   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .local  _ZStL8__ioinit
    .comm   _ZStL8__ioinit,1,1
    .section    .rodata.cst8,"aM",@progbits,8
    .align 8
.LC0:
    .long   921391986
    .long   -1077349148
    .align 8
.LC2:
    .long   2858241566
    .long   -1075525036
    .hidden __dso_handle
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 9.2.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

**Edit II**

As requested, `objdump -d` on the executable compiled with `-O0` can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/vsTw3CGF) (I cannot post it here because of length constraint). Output of `ldd` indicates that the executable is linked agains `/usr/lib/libm.so.6`. A part of the output of `objdump -d /bin/libm.so.6` (sections .init, .plt, sin and cos) is found [here](https://pastebin.com/1rH80H1X).

Comment: Cannot reproduce on wandbox either with your exact command, maybe your architecture matters?

Comment: The assembly reveals the `-O0` version does the math in the program at run time, and the `-O1` version does the math in the compiler at compile time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `-O1`, the floating computation happens at compile time, using the [GNU MPFR library](https://www.mpfr.org/).  MPFR is expected to give a correctly rounded result even for functions such as `sin` and `cos`.  Your math library likely has different accuracy goals for these functions, which is why run-time computation (at the `-O0` optimization level) sometimes gives different results.  For example, the [GNU C library has a general accuracy goal *of a few  ulp*](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Errors-in-Math-Functions.html).

Reportedly, IEEE 754 only has accuracy requirements for a subset of the math library functions (`sqrt`, apparently), which enables math libraries to choose different trade-offs between speed and accuracy for the transcendental functions. (I do not have access to IEEE 754 because IEEE is opposed to the open dissemination of knowledge unfortunately.)

Comment: Interesting. 1) Can you provide a link to gcc documentation that states that MPFR library is used at compile time. 2) The example in the question stems from a long loop in a program, where pseudo-random numbers are obtained from a linked library (```theta``` and ```v``` are essentially the random numbers I get at some point). I doubt that ```gcc``` does the loop at compile time, still I get the same discrepancy with -O1 and -O0. Could it be that -O1 uses an alternative library also at runtime? (this might be another SO question)

Comment: @francesco [*"The GCC middle-end has been integrated with the MPFR library. This allows GCC to evaluate and replace at compile-time calls to built-in math functions having constant arguments with their mathematically equivalent results. In making use of MPFR, GCC can generate correct results regardless of the math library implementation or floating point precision of the host platform. This also allows GCC to generate identical results regardless of whether one compiles in native or cross-compile configurations to a particular target"*](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html#mpfropts)

Answer (score 1):

While the other answer already explains why you are seeing different behavior between `-O0` (evaluated at run-time with slightly imperfect results and unspecified rounding) and `-O1` (evaluated at compile-time with exact results and rounding), I want to add an explanation of why it was difficult for me to reproduce your particular output with `-O0`. I always observed the output

```
-0x1.8f4e436eb5372p-3 -0x1.4ca54aa5d4e1ep-1
```

on both my own my machine and the compiler explorer.

The reason is that you most likely are using a glibc compiled with the `-mfma` flag, i.e. using FMA3. I have tested through the `-march` switches for gcc and was able to narrow it down to that.

On my machine with a Kaby Lake processor, gcc 9.2 and glibc 2.29, compiling glibc with `-O2 -march=native` and the executable with `-O0` I get the output

```
-0x1.8f4e436eb5371p-3 -0x1.4ca54aa5d4e1ep-1
```

Compiling glibc with `-O2 -march=native -mno-fma` and the executable with `-O0` I get

```
-0x1.8f4e436eb5372p-3 -0x1.4ca54aa5d4e1ep-1
```

In either case compiling the executable with `-O1` gives:

```
-0x1.8f4e436eb5372p-3 -0x1.4ca54aa5d4e1ep-1
```

Looking at the disassembly for `sin` and `cos` with FMA3 enabled, it is clear that these instructions are used. The fused-multiply-add causes one less rounding of the intermediate results and can thereby change the output of `cos` and/or `sin` slightly. I suspect that this is the reason that the code in question produces slightly different output depending on optimization flags of glibc. As explained in the other answer this difference does however fall into the range of documented divergence for these functions.

As to why the compiler is allowed to use the FMA3 instructions, although it changes the result of floating point operations, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34436233/fused-multiply-add-and-default-rounding-modes).

---

There is also a feature called *multi-arch* in glibc, that if enabled will link differently optimized math functions at runtime to fit the architecture the program is running on. If this is enabled and your CPU supports FMA3 (e.g. Haswell and up), then you will also be seeing your results.