# How to reduce the precision of a double in C?

Tags: floating-point, double, precision

I'm trying to reduce the precision of `double` variables in C to test the effect on the results. I tried doing a bitwise `&`, but it gives an error.

How can I do this on `float` and `double` variables?

Comment: What do you really want to do? Literally just chop some bits off the signifcand? Why? Do you care about the digits of the number in decimal? Floating-point values can be split into high and low parts using normal floating-point operations with [Dekker’s algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14285800/298225).

Answer (score 1):

> How to reduce the precision of a double in C?

To reduce the relative precision of a floating point numbers such that various least significant bits of the [significand/mantissa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand) are zero'd, code needs to access the significand.

---

Use `frexp()` to extract the signicand and exponent of the FP number.

Scale the signicand with `ldexp()` and then round, truncate, or floor - depending in coding goals - to remove precision.  Truncation is shown, yet I recommend rounding via `rint()`

Scale back and add back the exponent.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double reduce(double x, int precision_power_2) {
  if (isfinite(x)) {
    int power_2;

    // The frexp functions break a floating-point number into a 
    // normalized fraction and an integral power of 2.
    double normalized_fraction = frexp(x, &power_2);  // 0.5 <= result < 1.0 or 0

    // The ldexp functions multiply a floating-point number by an integral power of 2
   double less_precise = trunc(ldexp(normalized_fraction, precision_power_2));
   x = ldexp(less_precise, power_2 - precision_power_2);

  }
  return x;
}

void testr(double x, int pow2) {
  printf("reduce(%a, %d --> %a\n", x, pow2, reduce(x, pow2));
}

int main(void) {
  testr(0.1, 5);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
//       v-53 bin.digs-v             v-v 5 significant binary digits  
reduce(0x1.999999999999ap-4, 5 --> 0x1.9p-4
```

Use `frexpf()`, `ldexp()`, `rintf()`, `truncf()`, `floorf()`, etc. for `float`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to apply the bitwise and `&`, you need to apply it to the integer representation of the `float` value:

```
float f = 0.1f;
printf("Befor: %a %.16e\n", f, f);
unsigned int i;
_Static_assert(sizeof f == sizeof i, "pick integer type of the correct size");
memcpy(&i, &f, sizeof i);
i &= ~ 0x3U; // or any other mask.
            // This one assumes the endianness of floats is identical to integers'
memcpy(&f, &i, sizeof f);
printf("After: %a %.16e\n", f, f);
```

Note that this does not provide you with 29-bit IEEE-754-like numbers. The value in `f` was first rounded as a 32-bit single-precision number, and then brutally truncated.

A more elegant method relies on a floating-point constant with two bits set:

```
float f = 0.1f;
float factor = 5.0f; // or 3, or 9, or 17
float c = factor * f;
f = c - (c - f);
printf("After: %a %.16e\n", f, f);
```

The advantage of this method is that it rounds `f` to the nearest value using N bits of significand, as opposed to truncating it towards zero as in the first method. However, the program is still computing with 32-bit IEEE 754 floating-point and then rounding to fewer bits, so the result is still not always equivalent to what a narrower floating-point type would have produced.

The second method relies on an idea by Dekker, described online in [this article](http://www-pequan.lip6.fr/~graillat/papers/REC08_Paper_Graillat.pdf).

Comment: I don't get it: f = c - (c - f);  IS  f = c - c + f;  IS  f = f;

Comment: @Goularou The first step in your reasoning assumes floating-point addition is associative, but it's not. See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/10371890/139746